# How can I add Themed Cell Styles to a cell using xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to look for the method which lets me add a Themed cell style to a cell in an Excel sheet or replicate it. I want to do add this: https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/cell-styles.html

I looked at all the documentations and could not find any method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can I add Themed Cell Styles to a cell using xlsxwriter?

No. Cell styles aren't supported in XlsxWriter.